# Group by and aggregate functions in dynamic SQL Pivot Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have formulated the following dynamic SQL Query to turn an unkown number of row values (Maschine Names as nvarchar) into columns. The Row Values of the Pivoted Columns should be the sum of downtime and maintenance time (both int) for the particular Maschine.

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(Maschines)
  FROM (SELECT Maschines FROM Rawdata AS p
  GROUP BY MASCHINE) AS x;
SET @sql = N'
SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM(

  SELECT * from Rawdata
   ) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM(maintenance) FOR Maschines IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  +')
) AS p;';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

The Query returnes the Summed up maintenance time, but once i try to include more than one column in the sum ( like Sum(maintenance+downtime) ) i get an error close to '+'.

In addition, the query returns a pivoted table, but still has the same number of rows, however i need a result that is grouped for the unkown number of columns, thus containing only one row

Answer (score 0):

So unfortunately PIVOT in SQL is fairly limited in that you can only perform a single aggregation of a single column.

Your best option is instead of just doing

```
Select * from rawdata
```

as your source, include a column that pre-adds maintenance and downtime together, like

```
select *, maintenance + downtime as TotalTime from rawdata
```

and then aggregate it.